# How to get the current URL after a redirect in a Symfony2 WebTestCase?

Tags: testing, symfony

Using the Symfony2 WebTestCase, I have the following test :

```
$client->request('GET', '/');
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse() instanceof RedirectResponse);

$crawler = $client->followRedirect();
```

I would like to test **the new url, after the redirection** ends with `/login` but I have found no way to access the new URL.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can get the current URL with `$client->getResponse()->headers->get('location')`, and assert it ends with */login* using `assertRegExp()`.

```
$this->assertRegExp('/\/login$/', $client->getResponse()->headers->get('location'));
```

Comment: Works for Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 26):

Just tried Samy Dindane solution without success (maybe something changed from 2.0)

Anyway, in 2.1, I was able to retrieve current URL in test with:

```
$client->getRequest()->getUri()
```

Then, you can use assertRegexp().

Comment: Not true in symfony 2.3

Answer (score 14):

You can also do something like this (Symfony 2.3)

```
$client->getHistory()->current()->getUri()
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add this row `$client->getResponse()->getTargetUrl()` before `$client->followRedirect()` to get the url where you will be redirected

Comment: Without a doubt my preferred answer if you want the URL without following the redirect. Note that in order to make this validate in your IDE, you can do the following (taken from my unit test, thus the assertions): `$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect());
/** @var RedirectResponse $response */
$response = $client->getResponse();
$this->assertEquals($new_url, $response->getTargetUrl());`

Answer (score 2):

Test redirect from /sample to /target (can be absolute url as well)

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', '/sample');

$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse() instanceof RedirectResponse);
$this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/target'));
```

Comment: Working on Symfony 5.0. You can have this assertion `isRedirect` and then follow that redirect with: `$client->followRedirect();`