# Symfony tests, making request does not find routes

Tags: symfony, phpunit

**Symfony 6**

According to [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#write-your-first-application-test) I am writing a WebTestCase.

The controller to be tested delivers json coded array data and works fine.

But the test itself cannot load from the URL. All I get is a 404 error.

The URL is: *http://masch1/company/public/get/data?active=1&sort=desc*

**This is my test**

```
<?php

// php bin/phpunit tests/Controller/DataControllerTest.php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DataControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://masch1/company/public/get/data?active=1&sort=desc');

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('h1', 'Hello World');
    }
}
```

The tutorial itself says that hardcoding the request URLs is a best practice for application tests.

In my desperation I tried different combinations.

- http://masch1/company/public/get/data\
- /company/public/get/data
- /public/get/data

etc.

But all I get when running is:

> /var/www/company/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/BrowserKitAssertionsTrait.php:142
> /var/www/company/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/BrowserKitAssertionsTrait.php:33
> /var/www/company/tests/Controller/DataControllerTest.php:15
>
> Caused by ErrorException: No route found for "GET
> http://localhost/company/public/get/data" in
> /var/www/company/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:127
> Stack trace:
> #0 /var/www/company/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Test/BrowserKitAssertionsTrait.php(33):
> Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::assertThatForResponse()
> #1 /var/www/company/tests/Controller/DataControllerTest.php(15): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase::assertResponseIsSuccessful()
> #2 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1608):
> App\Tests\Controller\DataControllerTest->testSomething()
> #3 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(1214):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runTest()
> #4 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestResult.php(728):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->runBare()
> #5 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php(964):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult->run()
> #6 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(684):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase->run()
> #7 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php(651):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run()
> #8 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(144):
> PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner->run()
> #9 /var/www/company/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php(97): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
> #10 /var/www/company/bin/phpunit(11): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
> #11 {main}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be because you used a full URL in the test instead of a relative URL.  WebTestCase class automatically creates a client that simulates a browser, but it doesn't actually send HTTP requests, it directly calls the Symfony application.

Try the following code:

```
<?php

// php bin/phpunit tests/Controller/DataControllerTest.php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DataControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        // Use a relative path instead of a full URL
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/get/data?active=1&sort=desc');

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $this->assertSelectorTextContains('h1', 'Hello World');
    }
}
```

This way, the client will automatically use the default domain and port (usually localhost:8000) to access the application. Of course, you can also pass an array parameter when creating the client to change the default values:

```
$client = static::createClient(['HTTP_HOST' => 'masch1']);
```

For more information about the WebTestCase class and the client, refer to the following links:

- [Testing (Symfony Docs)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html)
- [Using Symfony Bundle FrameworkBundle Test WebTestCase instead of PHPUnitFrameworkTestCase as a base class for our tests gives us a nice abstraction for functional tests. The $client variable simulates a browser. Instead of making HTTP calls to the server though, it calls the Symfony application directly.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/17-tests.html)
- [How to get the current URL after a redirect in a Symfony2 WebTestCase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047305/how-to-get-the-current-url-after-a-redirect-in-a-symfony2-webtestcase)

Comment: Brilliant. That's it. All I needed was the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed was the right way to insert the Url.

```
<?php

// php bin/phpunit tests/Controller/DataControllerTest.php
namespace App\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class DataControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testSomething(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient(['HTTP_HOST' => 'masch1']);
        $client->request('GET', '/get/data?active=1&sort=desc');
        $response = $client->getResponse();
        $content = $response->getContent();
        
        // Check json data with first record
        $jsonData = json_decode($content, true)[0];

        // check fields
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('field1', $jsonData);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('field2', $jsonData);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('field3', $jsonData);

        // Check field types
        $this->assertIsInt($jsonData['field1']);

        $this->assertEquals(200, $response->getStatusCode());

        $this->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        
    }
}
```